# Passing ServiceClientCredentials as a paramater to a constructor in C#

Tags: c#, rest

I'm trying to implement a REST API client in C# where the constructor takes a parameter off Microsoft.Rest.ServiceClientCredentials. Since it's an abstract class I can't instantiate it and pass it on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The abstract class is a template. You can't instantiate a template since there is missing functionlity in it, rendering it incomplete. You can instantiate derived class though.

Check the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.rest.serviceclientcredentials?view=azure-dotnet) for derived credential classes and pick the one that's fitting to your case.

If you are looking for a username/password case, the [BasicAuthenticationCredentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.rest.basicauthenticationcredentials?view=azure-dotnet) is the concrete class for you.

You can instantiate it

```
var bauthCredentials = new BasicAuthenticationCredentials();
functionThatTakesServiceClientCredentials(bauthCredentials);
```

And the function is something like this:

```
public void functionThatTakesServiceClientCredentials(ServiceClientCredentials bauthCredentials) {
    // Do stuff
}
```